# pi 3 stuck on rainbow screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I installed a fresh version of Raspbian OS full via the raspberry pi imager tool but my pi is just stuck at the rainbow screen and wont load, even after 10min.

The power supply should work because it was already working before with the same pi. The SD card is also brand new and I don't have any old card I could test. I formatted the card and installed the os again but without success...

Any idea what I could try to fix my pi?

Edit: Tried for testing to install Manjaro ARM KDE but that also doesn't boot

---

Edit2: I tried nearly all versions of raspbian a few times now. The 32 bit, 64bit, full, lite, legacy, the normal one. 80% of the time it will stay frozen at the rainbow screen but sometimes it will print text on the screen that says it is unable to boot /boot and also only ext4-fs errors.

I also found a second power supply but that didn't change anything.

So now I guess the pi is broken from just sitting in a shelf for a few months or my brand new 32gb intenso sd card is also faulty or incompatible...

---

Edit3:
Found another sd card 16gb from sandisk. Now at the first startup, where was the information that the partition will get resized and the Pi did a restart. After that and some loading time I got a text output that said that debian is loading and the default user pi will be logged in on tty1 and after that the pi restarted again.

So now and everytime I start the pi, I see a `_` blinking at the corner of the screen, followed by my monitor going black for a second. Then the blinking `_` again with the follow up black screen. After that the `_` will freeze and not blink anymore. After some seconds my monitor will lose the signal and turns into standby.

So right now I guess the Pi is broken or something wich made me wonder because it was working before I stored it in a shelf..

Comment: `The power supply should work because it was already working before` ... that is same as *"how can he be dead, I just taked to him yesterday"*

Comment: Bullseye can have issues with some screens, try Raspberry Pi OS Legacy.

Comment: @jsotola Found another power supply. But it wil stay frozen in the rainbow screen. I also added new informations to the question in edit2

Comment: How sure are you of the HDMI cable? 
Can you swap it with another?

Comment: @Abel Yeah I finaly got it. I tryed every raspbian version without success with the 32gb card but I only tested the recomendet version on the 16gb card. I tested other version and the legacy version on the 16gb card did work! Maybe the pi just dont like the 32gb intenso card..